# Bugsnag is throwing invalid api key: '' error

Tags: go, go-gin, bugsnag

I am using go v1.19 to build a go application. I have run this application using a service file in linux OS.

Below in my code to initialize the bugsnag:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go"
    bugsnaggin "github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go-gin"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func init() {
    BugsnagAutoNotify()
}
func main() {
    InitRoutes()
}

var routes = Routes{
    Route{"GET", "/test", test},
}

func InitRoutes() {
    router := gin.Default()
    for _, route := range routes {
        switch route.Method {
        case "GET":
            router.GET(route.Url, route.HandlerFunc)
        case "POST":
            router.POST(route.Url, route.HandlerFunc)
        default:
            router.GET(route.Url, func(c *gin.Context) {
                c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                    "result": "Specify a valid http method with this route.",
                })
            })
        }
    }
    router.Run(":8080")
}

func BugsnagAutoNotify() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return bugsnaggin.AutoNotify(bugsnag.Configuration{
        APIKey:          bugsnagApiKey,
        ProjectPackages: []string{"main"},
        AppVersion:      bugsnagAppVersion,
    })
}
```

But when I call `bugsnag.Notify(err, metadata)` in test handler it says following:

```
bugsnag/defaultReportPublisher.publishReport: bugsnag/payload.deliver: invalid api key: ''
```

whats wrong here ?

Comment: Is `bugsnagApiKey` set properly?

Comment: Yes I printed it before calling AutoNotify()

Comment: is there any solution to this issue yet? I'm facing the same challenge right now

Comment: @Victor.Uduak I have posted my answer, please check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the import statement to `"github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go/v2"` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having problems with this please feel free to write in to support@bugsnag.com.